# vue-router@4.2.5 error: uncaught error during route navigation

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router4

The page didn't navigate correctly when I use `router.push`:

```
[Vue Router warn]: uncaught error during route navigation:
warn @ vue-router.mjs:35
vue-router.mjs:3471  TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'catch' in undefined
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPnv5.png)

Comment: can you add your code? it should be $route.push, not router.push

Comment: @ManhDo no, it is [router.push](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html#Navigate-to-a-different-location).  It makes sense that the router handles routing functions.

Comment: Error is likely a bad router config or typo somewhere.  There are [many](https://www.google.com/search?q=vue-router+Cannot+use+%27in%27+operator+to+search+for+%27catch%27+site:stackoverflow.com) questions and answers related to this exact problem.

Comment: thanks, @yodud, my falt, typo error. it is $router.push, like this [docs router vuejs](https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/navigation.html)